# Download Latest Exported File from Directory

Tags: php, mysql, csv, download, directory

I have a script which is exporting files to a CSV file from a MySQL Database.  I am wanting to create a link to download the latest file from the directory.  Is there a way to do with PHP?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can compare file modification time of all files in that folder and get the latest one

```
$lastestFile = "";
$lastestTime  = 0 ;
$path = "../";

foreach ( new DirectoryIterator ( $path ) as $file ) {
    if ($file->getBasename () == "." || $file->getBasename () == "..")
        continue;

    if($lastestTime < $file->getMTime() )
    {
        $lastestTime =  date("Y-m-d g:i:s",$file->getMTime());
        $lastestFile = $file->getBasename();
    }
}

var_dump($lastestFile,$lastestTime);
```

Output

```
string 'webservice' (length=10)
string '2012-04-19 11:15:50' (length=19)
```

Comment: so as I have two files which have been put into a directory such as:
1336016206.csv
1336016207.csv
How exactly would I download the latest file from the above script

Comment: it would still work but since your file are in integer format a sort would have been ok but not as valid as last modification date ...